# What Alt text to use on a list of images (of books)

Tags: wcag

On a page I have a list of books (only the name and the authors), with their coverpage.

**What alt-text should I use on those images?**

I have seen a large Dutch online webshop which has the name of the product in the product image;

I have seen 'product details' on all items a page on Amazon with lots of products (so they all have the same alt text)

I wonder what would be good to have when someone has a screenreader. Should I just make it blank so it gets ignored? That sounds lazy, but I don't know what good it would be to listen to the screenreader read 30 books and then say at every book either 'this is a cover image' or the title of the book (which it also reads out because it is the start of the book-paragraph, so then it would be read twice)

Comment: Most cases of deciding the best alternative text for an image rely on context. Do you have a screen shot or sample code to post?

Comment: Nothing more than a layout scetch; it's a 3 column table with in each column a small thumb of a bookcover (approx 100 pixels heigh) and next to it the title of the book and the author of the book. Something like this http://www.nybooks.com/ipl/ but then with less text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a layout that might look like this:

```
+-----------------+
|                 |  Night Circus
|                 |  Erin Morgenstern
|                 |
|                 |  ISBN
|                 |  A story of something or other, though
|                 |  I cannot be sure as the book is too
|                 |  far away to see clearly.
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

I would use a blank `alt` attribute. Stating the title / author is just verbose and adds nothing. Now, if your site is also pitching the cover art as a selling point, then I would craft custom alternative text for each image. But I don't think that fits here.

Redundant alternative text is frustrating for most screen reader users.

Comment: Am I right that an empty alt tag is just ignored by  a screenreader?

Comment: Yes. To be a bit more precise (as it matters with some elements/attributes), an `<img>` with an empty `alt` attribute is ignored by screen readers. Or `<img src="…" alt="">`.

Answer (score 1):

If the images meet the [definition of pure decoration per WCAG 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#puredecdef), as they might from your description, then an empty alt attribute is appropriate (`alt=""`).  Note that you must also either make sure there is no `title` attribute or that it is also empty in order for the images to be ignored by assistive technology.  See [WCAG technique H67](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H67.html) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the addition